# Optaplanner termination property not Working according to given time

Tags: drools, optaplanner

```
<scoreDirectorFactory>
    <scoreDrl>Optaplanner/TaskScheduling.drl</scoreDrl>
</scoreDirectorFactory>


<constructionHeuristic>
    <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT</constructionHeuristicType>
</constructionHeuristic>




 <localSearch>
        <localSearchType>HILL_CLIMBING</localSearchType>
    </localSearch>

<termination>

    <bestScoreLimit>0hard/0soft</bestScoreLimit>

    <minutesSpentLimit>5</minutesSpentLimit>

  
</termination>
```

Here is the configuration file am using but the solver does not  entertain time of termination

'''Solving started: time spent (216), best score (-20init/2000hard/0soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), random (JDK with seed 0).
Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: time spent (752), best score (24800hard/618soft), score calculation speed (528/sec), step total (20).
Solving ended: time spent (764), best score (24800hard/618soft), score calculation speed (369/sec), phase total (2), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE).'''

Answer (score 1):

The default composition style for multiple termination conditions is `OR`. As the score attained after the Construction Heuristic phase (24800hard/618soft) > 0hard/0soft, the first condition about `bestScoreLimit` was satisfied and the solver terminated.

Please see more about termination composition in the [documentation](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#combiningMultipleTerminations):

Comment: Yes you are right i have some issue in score Calculation. yes i have fixed it now its working , Thanks for  your Help